# Inbox shows more answers than were posted

Tags: bug, answers

In my inbox, it says there are 2 answers to this question, but when I go to the question, there's only one answer:

[image: Screenshot showing discrepancy between inbox and question page]

I'd guess this is a quirk of the 5 minute grace period, where instead of a user editing their answer in the first 5 minutes they instead deleted it.  If so, I find it pretty odd that doing so completely deletes the answer, there's no deleted answer on this post.

Comment: Deleting in the grace period doesn't remove it entirely, just tried.

Comment: The image seems to be broken so I can't actually see what you're talking about, but don't comments also get rolled up into the same notification?  And those _don't_ stick around when deleted, but I'm not sure what happens to their notifications...

Comment: @Izkata Weird that you can't see the image. It's uploaded to the SE Imgur servers.

Comment: @Keen Ah, got it now.  It couldn't find the server before, probably just a weird routing issue.

Comment: Do you have screenshot that is wider? (as in, including the timestamps on the posted answer and question)? It may be related to that possibly?